# Uniform distribution, chi square test

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, uniform-distribution, order-statistics, chi-squared

What test or procedure can I use to determine the **best** estimate $\alpha\in [0,1]$ whether given $N$ numbers
come from the uniform distribution in the interval $[0,\theta]$ for a given
$\theta>0$? I've heard that chi-square test can be used for this purpose but 
I do not know how exactly.Also a Matlab command could be given to determine my $\alpha$ or at least to say yes/no.

Comment: What does $\alpha$ represent?

Comment: I would like to represent it the probability that our $N$ numbers come from a uniform distribution. Maybe that I'm too optimistic about its existence but it should be close to $1$ if we have uniformly distributed numbers and close to $0$ if not. It would be useful to develop some theory about this $\alpha$.

Comment: For that kind of analysis, you would need a Bayesian approach with the prior probability of your hypothesis being true and prior probabilities of alternative specified hypotheses.  I suspect this is not the route you are trying to go down.  Alternatively you might prefer a likelihood, but this may not tell you much more than whether $\theta$ is at least the maximum of your observations

Comment: The Bayesian approach is not so bad option if I knew how to apply it to observations $X_1,...,X_n$ with some trivial priors.